# SuiteTalk(Netsuite) C# Console App Web Services Matrix Assembly Item

Tags: c#, netsuite, suitetalk

In NetSuite Web Service, for Inventory Item there is an attribute called matrixType which is responsible for  defining the parent child relationship. This attribute accepts value as _parent or _child. But this attribute is not available in to update in Assembly Item via NetSuite’s web-service

However, it is available if we try to do an Import via CSV. In which case we can define an item as Inventory type or Assembly type and can also define matrixType (Parent or Child) attribute.

I'm unable to find that if there is a way to do this via web-service.

Can any one help on this?

Answer (score 0):

In Web Service Item class has matrixTypeField field

```
public ItemMatrixType matrixType 
{
            get {
                return this.matrixTypeField;
            }
            set {
                this.matrixTypeField = value;
            }
 }
```

And

```
public enum ItemMatrixType {

        /// <remarks/>
        _parent,

        /// <remarks/>
        _child,
    }
Item.matrixType = ItemMatrixType._parent;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But Item matrix type is available in InventoryItem Class not in AssemblyItem. We need the available option in assemblyItem.